# I'm having an innodb endless transaction problem

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I am using MariaDB version 11.0.2 and I am having the following problem. I cannot perform any operation on the related row in the database. The transaction text below does not go in any way. I don't know what to do or how to solve it. I'm doing research on the subject on Google, but the solutions are out of date or I can't reach any results.

```
=====================================
2023-07-16 10:24:13 0x7ff7f81a9640 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 47 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 0 srv_active, 6794 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 6794
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 3054
Purge done for trx's n:o < 3054 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 2668, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 6797 sec recovered trx
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
--------
FILE I/O
--------
Pending flushes (fsync): 0
3302 OS file reads, 29 OS file writes, 30 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 67754925
Log flushed up to   67754925
Pages flushed up to 67701222
Last checkpoint at  67701206
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 167772160
Dictionary memory allocated 1001072
Buffer pool size   8064
Free buffers       4706
Database pages     3358
Old database pages 1259
Modified db pages  69
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.856
Max dirty pages percent: 90.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 3218, created 140, written 0
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 3358, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 read views open inside InnoDB
state: sleeping
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of available RAM.

Comment: Does a SHOW PROCESSLIST show a transaction query in progress?

Comment: No, there aren't any proccess

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
---TRANSACTION 2668, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 6797 sec recovered trx
```

says that this is a transaction that was recovered in the `XA PREPARE` state. Are there any messages about recovered XA transactions in the server error log, near the time the server was last started up? Can you execute the command `XA RECOVER` to list all transactions in `XA PREPARE` state? It should also list the XID, which you can pass to the `XA COMMIT` or `XA ROLLBACK` statements. If the XID starts with `MySQLXid`, that should be something that the binlog (`log_bin`) internally uses to keep itself consistent with the InnoDB transaction commits. In that case, it should be a bug that the XID is not committed or rolled back during crash recovery or when preparing (applying log to) a hot backup.